# Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, asmx

I'm having an issue calling an asmx webservice:

Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority ...

When I go to the asmx url in a browser on the server (WIN2k12R2 fully patched as of 6 Sep 2016) making the requests I don't see any issue with the certificate.  It's issued by COMODO RSA Extended Validation Secure Server CA (Intermediate Certification Authorities), which is issued by COMODO RSA Certification Authority (Intermediate Certification Authorities), which is issued by AddTrust External CA Root (Trusted Root Certification Authorities) - all report ok.

The time on the server (UTC) is synced with 3.europe.pool.ntp.org

I'm using the proxy that was built by Visual Studio.

I've moved the Intermediate COMODO certs to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities and no longer encountered the error - does this seem like a valid solution?  It appears to have solved the problem, but I don't understand why.

Comment: If the server is public, try checking it with SSL Labs server test (https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html). The issue may be due to the server not sending the full certificate chain in the handshake.

Comment: @AnandBhat - as it happens I had already run an ssltest. My code interacts with 2 separate webservices - 1 has an explicit requirement for TLS1.2 and the other did not - I made the assumption that TLS1.2 would work for both - that was my mistake. 1 service has a C rated cert (because it doesn't support TLS1.2!!), the other has a A rated cert. I used ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol=SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 which caused the service with the C rated cert to fail! Using ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol=SecurityProtocolType.Tls12|SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 allows both to work! Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority '\*'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463485/could-not-establish-secure-channel-for-ssl-tls-with-authority)