# WCF Web Service Reference with .NET standard 2.0

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, .net-standard-2.0

I am generating a WCF Web Service Reference `reference.cs` in a .NET Standard 2.0 project then using it from a .NET 4.7.1 project but I get `"Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority"`

If I generate it using`Add Service Reference` aside from visual studio 2015. I get a similar reference.cs class and if I copy it in my .NET standard 2.0 project that would work but I lose the Async call implementation of the WCF Web service. Is there any way to make this work ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority '\*'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463485/could-not-establish-secure-channel-for-ssl-tls-with-authority)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you configure the Bindings. They are in the app.config in a .net framework project but should be encapsuled in a `BasicHttpBinding` in .NET Standard/.NET Core.

That way you can specify the security settings as needed:

```
    binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
    binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
    binding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None;
```

From Nuget package System.ServiceModel.Http:

```
namespace System.ServiceModel
{
    public class BasicHttpBinding : HttpBindingBase
    {
        public BasicHttpBinding();
        public BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode securityMode);

        public BasicHttpSecurity Security { get; set; }

        public override IChannelFactory<TChannel> BuildChannelFactory<TChannel>(BindingParameterCollection parameters);
        public override BindingElementCollection CreateBindingElements();
    }
}
```