# Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'www.docusign.net'

Tags: docusignapi

I am getting error (Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'www.docusign.net'.) when we are calling login web method of this web service (i.e. https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/credential.asmx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority '\*'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463485/could-not-establish-secure-channel-for-ssl-tls-with-authority)

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things this could be. I'd recommend checking the following first:

- TLS 1.0 is not supported - you'll need to confirm your application is using TLS 1.1 or 1.2
- Your application may not trust the DocuSign certificate chain. From the [DocuSign Trust Site's Certificate list](https://www.docusign.com/trust/compliance/public-certificates), the DigiCert root CA (969 bytes): Root CA for Demo/NA1/NA2/NA3/EU SSL certificates must be accepted.
- Networking issues: Your firewall may be altering or blocking the connection to DocuSign. Can you make a successful [SOAP Ping](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-soap-api/reference/Credential-API/Ping)?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem.
You just need to paste this code on the top of that code that was throwing this exception.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

And don't forget to add the namespace

```
using System.Net;
```