# "could not establish secure channel for ssl/tls with authority" on nested APIs

Tags: api, wcf

This may be a very simple issue but is (I think) complex to explain so, please bear with me.
We have a WCF API (written in C#) on our server which attaches to third-party APIs (a sort of one-stop place, if you will). These use a mixture of OAuth and certificates for security. The idea is that we don't have to put (the third party) certificates / security on all of our servers, just the one.
Therefore, the plan is for an application on one server to call the API on this server which calls the third-party API. This seems to work for all but one third-party.
If I use the Visual Studio (2017) inbuilt WCF Test Client on our API, it works fine. If I try to use our API from another application (by adding a service reference) **even on the same server** it fails with the above message.
Our API does not (yet) use https.
The plan is for use to release our API to others so we can't share any certificates / logins with them - this is the underlying reason for our API. 
I have done a lot of Googling about this and all of the answers seems to point to the certificate has to be on the calling application which would seem to defeat the object of our "catch all" API
I have probably not explained this very well - sorry. Maybe the issue could be summed up as "how do I stop the security being "passed down" to the calling application?"

Comment: without seeing the actual bindings you use client and server side there is nothing more left then guessing. Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463485

Comment: Thanks rene. As I said in my post, "I did a lot of Googling" and that was one of the posts I found "which seems to point to the certificate has to be on the calling application"

Comment: Which is not what we need here

Comment: I've no access to what you already googled. So, what is the binding you use on the client and server? Do you host in IIS? If a certificate is involved is it self-signed? Is the cert in all the required certificates stores, for example on the local machine but maybe also on the identity that runs the apppool.

Comment: Which binding are you referring to? the one on the application or the one on "our" API to the third-party? "Our" API is hosted in IIS on our server. The certificate (between "Our" API and the third-party - there is no certificate between the application and "our" API, as per my original post) is officially signed by the third-party. Since (as per my original post) the WCF test Client works, the certificate is correctly installed.

Comment: The certificate isn't correctly installed if you only installed it once AND host on IIS.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood my original post. We have an application A, "Our" API B and a third party API C. B to C has a certificate - this works fine using the WCF Test Client. A to B has no certificate, nor do we need it to have. A to B works fine for the other methods which attach to other third party APIs just not his particular one. Do this clarify?

Comment: i.e. A to B - no SSL. B to C - SSL and (working) certificate. A and B sit on our server. C is obviously somewhere else. B is hosted in our IIS.

Comment: Maybe configure tracing and logging for WCF: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/tracing-and-message-logging in both your server and client. Note that the wcf test client does have an .config file where you configure logging. Then you can create a known good and known bad logging. What left is painstakingly comparing for differences to hopefully find the root cause. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Okies - thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the culprit was the Application Pool Identity that "Our" API was running under. I changed that and now everything works as I would expect it to :)